# QEMU/KVM can't set qxl video ram size

Tags: windows-7, linux, video, qemu, linux-kvm

I'm trying to enlarge video memory size of qxl-vga device. Guest os (windows 7) shows only 16mb of video memory available. [I've installed windows guest tools](http://www.spice-space.org/download.html). When I'm trying to set more video memory there is still only 16mb available on the guest. Also performance doesn't change either. In fact even cursor is a bit laggy. I'm launching guest with that script

```
KVM_DIR=/var/lib/libvirt
IMAGE=win7.qcow2
NAME=win7
PORT=5914
RAM=4000
IFACE=win7
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m $RAM -drive file=$KVM_DIR/images/$IMAGE,if=virtio \
-name $NAME -device qxl-vga,id=video0,vgamem_mb=64,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 \
-spice port=$PORT,disable-ticketing -netdev tap,id=$IFACE,ifname=$IFACE \
-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=$IFACE -balloon virtio
```

My host is running Arch Linux:

```
% uname -a
Linux m0x35-pc 4.2.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Oct 27 08:13:28 CET 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Qemu version:

```
% qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 2.4.1, Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

[Win7 video settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxbsu.png)

Comment: Try setting `ram_size` and `vram_size` as well. See here: ovirt.org/documentation/draft/video-ram